TypeError: e.map is not a function and also showing html code in browser console after deploying
Getting this html code:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicon%202-BQiFomow.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Advanced Controls</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-HCdlHz6h.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-BwpwDN7P.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

and
TypeError: e.map is not a function
    at nM (index-HCdlHz6h.js:759:2344)
    at xd (index-HCdlHz6h.js:38:16997)
    at Zu (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:3139)
    at hg (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:44705)
    at fg (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:39703)
    at Wx (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:39631)
    at Oa (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:39485)
    at cc (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:35864)
    at ug (index-HCdlHz6h.js:40:34815)
    at E (index-HCdlHz6h.js:25:1559)

in the browser console.
I am serving the react app build or dist folder using pm2 serve. This issue is happening while calling an API.
To mention also: using vite, typescript.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried logging the api call's response. It is working in development server but not in production build.
